# Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\RAJESH\AndroidStudioProjects\flutte\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, dart, flutter

After re installing Android Studio I'm having this following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 4 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"4a13515b-84ae-422f-af52-                    
5d0ab7112e30","id":"1","progressId":null,"message":"Resolving     
dependencies..."}}]Resolving dependencies...

* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from:         C:\Users\RAJESH\AndroidStudioProjects\flutte\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --    debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/     folder.
```

UPDATE: This has been caused by low speed internet connection/and old builds in the build folder its been closed in the answer section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been solved by Running "flutter clean build" command in my opened flutter project and then i tested with sample Andorid Project,it runed well then i tried with a sample flutter project it runned with a delay of 4 to 5 minutes.!! The Key is "flutter clear build" command